# onAuthStateChanged not firing after updateProfile

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update the user's profile after he created his account, but i can't find a way to trigger `onAuthStateChanged()` after `updatingProfile()`.
It seems like updating user profile is not considering as an auth change...

App.js

```
import { auth } from '../../src/Firebase';

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log('Auth change detected')
      if (user) { 
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false)
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

SignUp.js

```
import { auth } from '../../src/Firebase';

const handleSignUp = async() => {
        try{
            setSending(true)
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: userName})
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }finally{
            auth.currentUser.reload() 
            setSending(false)
        }
    }
```

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { collection, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseconfig";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" 
  
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(firebase);
export const auth = initializeAuth(firebase,{persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)});
```

I want `onAuthStateChanged()` to be called after `updateProfile()`, so i can display the name in my app after logging in, do you have any ideas?

I tried using `auth.currentUser.reload()` but it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onAuthStateChanged` (as its name suggests) fires when the authentication **state** changes, so when a user signs in our out, or when the sign-in changes from one user to another. It does **not** fire when the profile of the already signed-in user changes.

If you want to also get notified of that, you can listen for [`onIdTokenChanged` events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onidtokenchanged). This will (as its name suggest) fire for any changes in the ID token.

Alternatively, you can just put whatever code you want to execute after the `await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: userName})` resolves (so on the line after it).

Comment: I tried to replace onAuthStateChanged by onIdTokenChanged but it still doesnt work

`await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`
`updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: userName})`

Comment: When i get the callback from onIdTokenChanged, my displayName is undefined.
When i reload the app, this is fine.

Comment: Yeah. Separately from when `onAuthStateChanged` is called, I actually don't think that calling `updateProfile` automatically updates the ID token in the client. It might merely update the profile on the server. In that case, you'll need to call [`reload` on the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userreload) or [force get a refreshed id token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usergetidtokenresult) to get the new user profile in the client.

Comment: My solution was indeed to call `auth.currentUser.reload()` after `updateProfile`
I used redux to manage the user because auth wasnt very reliable.

Then in `onIdTokenChanged`, i updated my user with the callback. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: [onAuthStateChanged not triggered after linking anonymous account with email and password credential](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4227) suggests to use **onIdTokenChanged**. this fixed the issue for me.